# Fill a ListBox with Excel files older than x month

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms

I'm making a WinForm project that shows me all the Excel files older than x months of a selected folder.
I can populate a `ListBox` with all the Excel files (see code below).
In selecting the older than x month, I don't succeed. I think I should work with the `LastWriteTime` but can’t find how to use it.

Can anyone help me to find a solution on this?

```
Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal folderPath As String)
    filesListBox.Items.Clear()

    Dim fileNames As String() =
        System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderPath,
            "*.xl*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

    For Each fileName As String In fileNames
        fileslistbox.Items.Add(fileName)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information on the a File Creation Time / Last Write Time is returned by the [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.IO.FileInfo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) class, which provides the Creation Time, Last Write Time and Last Access Time of a file through a [FileSystemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

See whether you need the File Creation Time or the Last Write Time, depending on what your requirements are.
The Last Access Time may return just the file Creation `DateTime`, depending on the  System.

An example, with a modified `ListFiles` method:
I've added a parameter to the method, `OlderThanMonths`, which is used to specify *how old* a file should be to be included in the list.
Here, the `DateTime` reference is `LastWriteTime`.

```
Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal folderPath As String, OlderThanMonths As Integer)
    filesListBox.Items.Clear()

    Dim fileNames As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xl*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

    ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
    For Each fileName As String In fileNames
        Dim FIinfo As New FileInfo(fileName)
        If FIinfo.LastWriteTime.AddMonths(OlderThanMonths) <= Date.Now Then
            filesListBox.Items.Add(fileName)
        End If
    Next
    ListBox1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

Or with a LINQ `Where()` filter:

```
Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal folderPath As String, OlderThanMonths As Integer)
    filesListBox.Items.Clear()

    filesListBox.Items.AddRange(
        Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xl*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
                  Where(Function(f) New FileInfo(f).LastWriteTime.AddMonths(OlderThanMonths) <= Date.Now).
                  ToArray())
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Just need to add an IF clause to check the Modified Date.

Check this code sample:

```
Private Sub ListFiles(ByVal folderPath As String)
    filesListBox.Items.Clear()

    Dim fileNames As String() =
        System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderPath,
            "*.xl*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

    For Each fileName As String In fileNames
        Dim dtFileModifiedDate As DateTime = IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(fileName)
        Dim dtCustomDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(20180401, "yyyyMMdd", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        If dtFileModifiedDate > dtCustomDate Then
            filesListBox.Items.Add(fileName)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```